# enumeration select using variable vb

Tags: vb.net, enumeration

I have a case where my enumeration is like this:

```
Public Const PREVIEWCREATE As Integer = -3
Public Const SETUP As Integer = -2
Public Const PREVIEW As Integer = -1
```

I then have a form post where i recover a string like:

```
Dim mode_custom_mode = request.Form("custom_mode")
```

I can do

```
Select Case UCase(mode_custom_mode)

    Case "PREVIEWCREATE"
        t.StartupModeId = StartupMode.PREVIEWCREATE
    Case "SETUP"
        t.StartupModeId = StartupMode.SETUP 
...
```

is there a more direct way in VB to do something like:

**t.StartupModeId = StartupMode.(mode_custom_mode)  ?????**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you'd want

```
private enum StartupMode
    PREVIEWCREATE = -3
    SETUP = -2
    PREVIEW  = -1
end enum

t.StartupModeId = [Enum].Parse(GetType(StartupMode), mode_custom_mode)
```

Comment: sorry - the cleint is posting to me the string value, i cant change that

Comment: Thanks for the assist - when i apply I get "Type provided must be an Enum."

Comment: Public consts and enumerations aren't the same. I'll revise my answer to exemplify.

Answer (score 0):

You mean how parse String into Enum? Try this:

```
Private Enum StartupMode
    PREVIEWCREATE
    SETUP
    PREVIEW
End Enum

t.StartupModeId = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(StartupMode), mode_custom_mode), StartupMode)
```

and is the same with:

```
t.StartupModeId = DirectCast([Enum].Parse(GetType(StartupMode), "PREVIEWCREATE"), StartupMode)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to do this.

```
private enum StartupMode
    PREVIEWCREATE = -3
    SETUP = -2
    PREVIEW  = -1
end enum

t.StartupModeId = [Enum].Parse(GetType(StartupMode), mode_custom_mode)
```